# Undefined constant PDO::ODBC_ATTR_USE_CURSOR_LIBRARY

Tags: php, laravel, pdo

I'm suddenly getting this error after my Mac crashed. Previously this error wasn't happening until it rebooted, so it seems something has become corrupted.

This is used in my `database.php` config file:

```
'options'   => [
    PDO::ODBC_ATTR_USE_CURSOR_LIBRARY => PDO::ODBC_SQL_USE_DRIVER,
],
```

I tried running `brew reinstall unixodbc` then `brew services restart php` but that didn't fix the issue.

I'm currently running Laravel Herd to serve my local Laravel projects, if that makes any difference.